# Copy a directory structure to ennumerated folders

Tags: bash, cp

My folder structure is like this:

```
ej-1/index.html
ej-1/js/scripts.js
ej-2/index.html
ej-2/js/scripts.js
...
ej-12/index.html
ej-12/js/scripts.js
```

Sometimes I need to re-structure the other ennumerated folders with a new default set of files and folders. For that end, I'm trying to copy the ideal folder base structure to the others, using the following:

```
cp -r ej-1/* ej-{2..12}/*
```

My expectation was:

```
ej-1/* -> ej-2/*
ej-1/* -> ej-3/*
...
ej-1/* -> ej-12/*
```

Instead, it copies the content of each folder to the last one, making some overwritting nonsense:

```
ej-1/* -> ej-12/*
ej-2/* -> ej-12/*
ej-3/* -> ej-12/*
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `cp` manual, with `man cp`. The relevant parts are as follows.

```
SYNOPSIS
       cp [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
DESCRIPTION
       Copy SOURCE to DEST, or multiple SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY.
```

By specifying multiple arguments, this is the format you are using. This copies multiple `SOURCE`s to a single `DIRECTORY`, which is *not* what you want. Instead, if you want to copy a single `SOURCE` to multiple directories, you could use something like a `for` loop, e.g.

```
for i in {2..12}; do cp -r ej-1/* ej-$i; done
```

N.B. This is untested. I've also removed the `*` globs from the destination, as they were unnecessary (from my interpretation of your question), and results in a single `DIRECTORY` for the `cp` command.

Comment: This works! Luckily, I have some basic programming knowledge built in me, yet utterly new to shell scripting. I didn't know the `for` is even simpler to write on a single line!

Comment: As for `man`: I'm actually on Windows using Cmder which has also a bash that I can execute and work with linux commands, and still the man command is not included, which is unfortunate. I wish to have it, but there's no documentation about installing it for this scenario.

Comment: @Fabián Glad it works! I can't really help with Cmder, but you should really try and get `man` working. It's a very accessible reference for these kind of things. (Sometimes a bit too terse, but definitely a good starting point.) I'm not sure if it's on topic here, but if not, maybe Superuser or somewhere else?